# A _______object is used for executing a static SQL statement and obtaining the results produced by it

Tags: java, jdbc

A _______object is used for executing a static SQL statement and obtaining the results produced by it.

- a) Statement
- b) db
- c) resultset
- d) sql

According to me the correct answer is Statement and Resultset both but when I am arguing to sir that both these are the correct answer he is denying that and saying the only correct answer is Statement. Could someone give a correct explanation why both of them are correct and the answer should be SQL since it has both Statement and Resultset.

Comment: I think that "sir" is correct.

Comment: Why should *Resultset  is used for executing a static SQL* be correct? Only the statement exectues a query. The resultset provided the result of the exectution. So a) is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone give a correct explanation why both of them are correct and the answer should be SQL since it has both Statement and Resultset.

A `ResultSet` does not execute an SQL statement.  Not ever.

A `Statement.execute()` call executes an SQL statement and returns a  `ResultSet`.   Thus:

- it executes an SQL statement, and
- it obtains the results as a `ResultSet`.

So, if you need to chose one of those four options:

- a) `Statement` is a correct answer; see above.
- c) `ResultSet` is not a correct answer; see above.
- b) and d) are not correct answers because there is no such thing as an "sql object" or a "db object" in the JDBC model.

And `Statement` + `ResultSet` is not an option.  If it was an option, it would also be (arguably) correct.

In short, "sir" is correct and you are incorrect.  Accept it.